# how to write header content type json data to csv file in php?

Tags: php, json, rest, csv, curl

we have been working with 3d cart rest response which we have successfully get here is my code.file name example.php which located in my wamp server

```
<?php

$host = 'https://apirest.3dcart.com';
$version = 1;
$service = 'Orders';
$secureUrl = 'https://xxxxyyyyy.3dcart.net';   // Secure URL is set in Settings->General->StoreSettings
$privateKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Private key is obtained when registering your app at http://devportal.3dcart.com
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';      // The token is generated when a customer authorizes your app
// initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init($host . '/3dCartWebAPI/v' . $version . '/' . $service);
// set headers
$httpHeader = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'SecureUrl: ' . $secureUrl,
        'PrivateKey: ' . $privateKey,
        'Token: ' . $token,
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
// [ ... addtional cURL options as needed ... ]
$response = curl_exec($ch);



if ($response === false) {
    $response = curl_error($ch);
}


curl_close($ch);
```

we have an access file on a browser using this URL http://localhost/social/example.php get a response in JSON like this without JSON encoded. but I want array this response so we can write CSV file.i have many try to google but no more luck for appropriate solution.thanks in advance.

```
[{"InvoiceNumberPrefix":"AB-","InvoiceNumber":1000,"OrderID":1,"CustomerID":1,"OrderDate":"2014-01-10T12:44:37","OrderStatusID":1,"LastUpdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","UserID":"","SalesPerson":"","ContinueURL":"http://71745179439.3dcart.net/continue_order.asp?orderkey=tl31S22wts7B0hF1","BillingFirstName":"John","BillingLastName":"Doe","BillingCompany":"","BillingAddress":"123 Street","BillingAddress2":"","BillingCity":"Coral Springs","BillingState":"FL","BillingZipCode":"33065","BillingCountry":"US","BillingPhoneNumber":"800-828-6650","BillingEmail":"test@3dcart.com","BillingPaymentMethod":"Online Credit Card","BillingOnLinePayment":true,"BillingPaymentMethodID":"1","ShipmentList":[{"ShipmentID":0,"ShipmentLastUpdate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","ShipmentBoxes":1,"ShipmentInternalComment":"Sample Order from 3dcart","ShipmentOrderStatus":1,"ShipmentAddress":"123 Street","ShipmentAddress2":"","ShipmentAlias":"","ShipmentCity":"Coral Springs","ShipmentCompany":"","ShipmentCost":0.0,"ShipmentCountry":"US","ShipmentEmail":"","ShipmentFirstName":"Test","ShipmentLastName":"Test","ShipmentMethodID":0,"ShipmentMethodName":"Free Shipping","ShipmentShippedDate":"","ShipmentPhone":"800-828-6650","ShipmentState":"FL","ShipmentZipCode":"33065","ShipmentTax":0.0,"ShipmentWeight":1.0,"ShipmentTrackingCode":"","ShipmentUserID":"","ShipmentNumber":1,"ShipmentAddressTypeID":0}],"OrderItemList":[{"CatalogID":3,"ItemIndexID":1,"ItemID":"1003K","ItemShipmentID":0,"ItemQuantity":1.0,"ItemWarehouseID":0,"ItemDescription":"Tote Bag
Color: Khaki","ItemUnitPrice":1.0,"ItemWeight":3.0,"ItemOptionPrice":0.0,"ItemAdditionalField1":"","ItemAdditionalField2":"","ItemAdditionalField3":"","ItemPageAdded":"Tote-Bag_p_3.html","ItemDateAdded":"2009-06-22T12:05:07","ItemUnitCost":0.0,"ItemUnitStock":5.0,"ItemOptions":",1","ItemCatalogIDOptions":"","ItemSerial":"","ItemImage1":"http://71745179439.3dcart.net/assets/images/default/handbag.jpg","ItemImage2":"http://71745179439.3dcart.net/assets/images/default/handbag.jpg","ItemImage3":"http://71745179439.3dcart.net/assets/images/default/handbag.jpg","ItemImage4":"http://71745179439.3dcart.net/assets/images/default/handbag.jpg","ItemWarehouseLocation":"","ItemWarehouseBin":"","ItemWarehouseAisle":"","ItemWarehouseCustom":""}],"PromotionList":[],"OrderDiscount":0.0,"SalesTax":0.0,"SalesTax2":0.0,"SalesTax3":0.0,"OrderAmount":1.0,"AffiliateCommission":0.0,"TransactionList":[],"CardType":"","CardNumber":"","CardName":"John Doe","CardExpirationMonth":"","CardExpirationYear":"","CardIssueNumber":"","CardStartMonth":"","CardStartYear":"","CardAddress":"","CardVerification":"","RewardPoints":"1","QuestionList":[],"Referer":"http://www.google.com","IP":"","CustomerComments":"Sample Order from 3dcart","InternalComments":"","ExternalComments":""}]
```

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode` ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: please use json_decode($response, true).

Comment: Before you do anything please validate your json http://jsonlint.com/ . A simple step that shows what's wrong. Then you can actually use json_decode() on your response.

Comment: i have tried json_decode it not work it only display 1. may be Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 so not work

Comment: Seems like your json is invalid which you provided here.

Comment: Check your json here as it it's not valid https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: thank...Elbarto  a problem is not JSON data format but my concern is how to write this data to direct CSV file.this data display on a webpage

Comment: You asked to put your json response in an array. We told you that you had to use json_decode($json, true) for that. But in order to do that you have to use a valid json string which you don't. Then only you could move on and use fputcsv() to solve your problem.

Comment: yes, Alberto, we have found an error in JSON format so we change  $service = 'Orders'; to  $service = 'Customer '; and get a valid response format we have check then after we write var_dump(json_decode($response, true)); its return int 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, all I have to find a solution write curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); then the return value from curl_exec will be the actual result from the successful operation and set false display it only browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` php function : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

On your code :

```
    <?php

    $host = 'https://apirest.3dcart.com';
    $version = 1;
    $service = 'Orders';
    $secureUrl = 'https://xxxxyyyyy.3dcart.net';   // Secure URL is set in Settings->General->StoreSettings
    $privateKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Private key is obtained when registering your app at http://devportal.3dcart.com
    $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';      // The token is generated when a customer authorizes your app
    // initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init($host . '/3dCartWebAPI/v' . $version . '/' . $service);
    // set headers
    $httpHeader = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'SecureUrl: ' . $secureUrl,
            'PrivateKey: ' . $privateKey,
            'Token: ' . $token,
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);
    // [ ... addtional cURL options as needed ... ]
    $response = curl_exec($ch);



    if ($response === false) {
        $response = curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

$arrayResponse = json_decode($response, true);
//Do something with your array
```

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

I don't know what is the structure of the csv file you want to output. You should provide it in your question if you want a better quality answer. Keep in mind though, that you are using 2 different data structures :

- JSON is a tree
- CSV is a table

So having nested arrays in your json will make this work harder.

## Step 1

Check if your json string is valid: [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/)
As you will see, the json string response you provided is not.

For the rest of my answer i will consider this part of your response which i made valid :

```
$string = '
[{
    "InvoiceNumberPrefix": "AB-",
    "InvoiceNumber": 1000,
    "OrderID": 1,
    "CustomerID": 1,
    "OrderDate": "2014-01-10T12:44:37",
    "OrderStatusID": 1,
    "LastUpdate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "UserID": "",
    "SalesPerson": "",
    "ContinueURL": "http://71745179439.3dcart.net/continue_order.asp?orderkey=tl31S22wts7B0hF1",
    "BillingFirstName": "John",
    "BillingLastName": "Doe",
    "BillingCompany": "",
    "BillingAddress": "123 Street",
    "BillingAddress2": "",
    "BillingCity": "Coral Springs",
    "BillingState": "FL",
    "BillingZipCode": "33065",
    "BillingCountry": "US",
    "BillingPhoneNumber": "800-828-6650",
    "BillingEmail": "test@3dcart.com",
    "BillingPaymentMethod": "Online Credit Card",
    "BillingOnLinePayment": true,
    "BillingPaymentMethodID": "1",
    "ShipmentList": [{
        "ShipmentID": 0,
        "ShipmentLastUpdate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ShipmentBoxes": 1,
        "ShipmentInternalComment": "Sample Order from 3dcart",
        "ShipmentOrderStatus": 1,
        "ShipmentAddress": "123 Street",
        "ShipmentAddress2": "",
        "ShipmentAlias": "",
        "ShipmentCity": "Coral Springs",
        "ShipmentCompany": "",
        "ShipmentCost": 0.0,
        "ShipmentCountry": "US",
        "ShipmentEmail": "",
        "ShipmentFirstName": "Test",
        "ShipmentLastName": "Test",
        "ShipmentMethodID": 0,
        "ShipmentMethodName": "Free Shipping",
        "ShipmentShippedDate": "",
        "ShipmentPhone": "800-828-6650",
        "ShipmentState": "FL",
        "ShipmentZipCode": "33065",
        "ShipmentTax": 0.0,
        "ShipmentWeight": 1.0,
        "ShipmentTrackingCode": "",
        "ShipmentUserID": "",
        "ShipmentNumber": 1,
        "ShipmentAddressTypeID": 0
    }],
    "OrderItemList": [{
        "CatalogID": 3,
        "ItemIndexID": 1,
        "ItemID": "1003K",
        "ItemShipmentID": 0,
        "ItemQuantity": 1.0,
        "ItemWarehouseID": 0
    }]
}]';
```

## Step 2

Use json_decode() to convert your json to an array this way : The 1st parameter is your json string and the 2nd is a boolean that when set to true will return an associative array. [(manual: json_decode)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

## Step 3

Create your csv file this way :

```
$f = fopen('output.csv', 'w');

foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result = [];
    array_walk_recursive($row, function($item) use (&$result) {
        $result[] = $item;
    });
    fputcsv($f, $result);
}
```

Of course my answer is based on the json string provided in step 1 !

Comment: Elbarto this JSON data display in a browser. access using  this URL http://localhost/social/example.php